# Copy paste a URL rarely works

Tags: firefox, chromium, url, paste

Why when I copy paste most of the URLs, to the address field in Chromium or Firefox, the `:` character is removed and gives an error? I already disabled the search in the address field that avoids other silly replacements (like copy paste a local URL and instead of going to that URL is makes a Google search).

For example:

```
http://cinecartaz.publico.pt/Filme/363839_capitao-fantastico#​
```

is replaced with

```
​http//cinecartaz.publico.pt/Filme/363839_capitao-fantastico#​
```

giving an error (of course).

How to fix this because is starting to really annoying me a lot!

Comment: This is not expected behavior, even for a browser trying to scrub data. I think we need a lot more information to help. Does copy/pasting a URL work as expected in other applications, such as LibreOffice or the terminal? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What keyboard setup do you have (language, etc.)? Does this continue to happen without any browser plugins enabled?

Comment: Yes it works normally in other applications and on the terminal I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have both OS and keyboard set for Portugal- Portugueses pt-PT. I do now have any plugins installed in the browsers. The problem occurs in Konqueror, Firefox and Chromium. If i copy a URL i can paste it correctly to the gedit for rxample. Only when i paste to the url field in the navigators, the problem occour (all the time).